# How not to capture the same error in a log when a powershell script runs every 5 minutes

Tags: powershell

I am now trying not to capture the same error in a log when the below script runs.
The script is running every 5 minutes. The goal is to store the last time the log was checked with a time stamp.
If there is no new entry (of the same error) when the script runs then there is nothing to do. (shouldn't send an Email) Else it should send an Email.

Thank you in advance for your time

```
$Date = Get-Date
$File = 'D:\...\...\logs\Nikos_text2.txt'
if ($content -like  '*Trigger action error*' | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get- 
 date).addMinutes(-5) } | Select-Object LastWriteTime) {
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("server name")
$objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$objMailMessage.From = "support@domain.com"
$objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
$objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
$objMailMessage.Subject = "Error message: 'Trigger action error'"
$objMailMessage.Body = "In log in server I traced the following error message: Trigger action error. 
  Pls check it asap"
$smtp.send($objMailMessage)
} else {
 break
}
```

I made some adjustments to my original code:

```
$File = 'D:\...\aurora\logs\Nikos_text2.txt'
$content = Get-Content $File
$date =(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$time = @(Get-Item $File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $date})
If (time -eq 'True' -and $content -like  '*Trigger action error*'){
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("server name")
$objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$objMailMessage.From = "support@domain.com"
$objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
$objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
$objMailMessage.Subject = "Error message: 'Trigger action error'"
$objMailMessage.Body = "In log in server I traced the following error message: 
 Trigger action error. Pls check it asap"
$smtp.send($objMailMessage)} else {
Exit
}
```

but now I don't receive any Email...
What have I done wrong?

Thank you in advance

This is how a log looks like:

```
    2021-01-05 13:02:14,657
ERROR  on 
[Processor... ] It is not allowed to disable this user: [WebContainer : 8](ConfigurationStore.java:143)

2021-01-05 13:02:14,657
ERROR  on 
## in: custom.moduleule.Processor@412971a2
[WebContainer : 8](ConfigurationStore.java:147)

2021-01-05 15:44:45,328
ERROR HttpContext on 
Application Error!
[WebContainer : 3](LoggingHelper.java:129)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com..apps.common.util.HttpContext.getAdminService(HttpContext.java:318)
    at com..apps.common.util.HttpContext.checkForProfileChange(HttpContext.java:908)
    at com..apps.common.util.HttpContext.getMenuData(HttpContext.java:925)
    at com..apps.sosa.util.MenuUtil.createMenuData(MenuUtil.java:181)
    at com..apps.sosa.util.MenuUtil.createTopLevelMenuData(MenuUtil.java:208)
    at com..apps.sosa.SoxPageLoaderAction.getTopLevelMenuData(SoxPageLoaderAction.java:208)
    at com..apps.common.PageLoaderAction.doLoad(PageLoaderAction.java:169)
    at com..apps.common.AbstractPageLoaderAction.doLoad(AbstractPageLoaderAction.java:99)
    at com..apps.common.AbstractLoaderAction.execute(AbstractLoaderAction.java:176)
    at com..apps.common.util.OPRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(OPRequestProcessor.java:656)
    at org..struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:341)
    at org..struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org..struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221)
    at com..apps.common.util.OPRequestProcessor.process(OPRequestProcessor.java:248)
    at org..struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org..struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1408)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:553)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3666)
    at com..wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.processSecurityPreInvokeException(CollaboratorHelper.java:145)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1199)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com..ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com..ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com..ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com..ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com..ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
    at com..ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:694)
    at com..ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com..ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com..io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com..io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com..io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com..io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com..io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com..io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com..ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
-- nested by --
2021-01-05 15:44:45
CODE       : 00002
LEVEL      : 4
NAME       : com.apps.common.util.ApplicationException
ERROR #    : UTUD3SIQY3Z0
TOKEN ID   : 2574333
USER       : System
MESSAGE    : The requested operation could not be completed.
    at com..apps.common.util.LoggingHelper.logError(LoggingHelper.java:128)
    at com..apps.common.util.ErrorHandler.log(ErrorHandler.java:644)
    at com..apps.common.util.ErrorHandler.handleError(ErrorHandler.java:131)
    at com..apps.common.util.ErrorHandler.handleError(ErrorHandler.java:100)
    at com..apps.common.AbstractLoaderAction.handleException(AbstractLoaderAction.java:926)
    at com..apps.common.AbstractPageLoaderAction.doLoad(AbstractPageLoaderAction.java:109)
    at com..apps.common.AbstractLoaderAction.execute(AbstractLoaderAction.java:176)
    at com..apps.common.util.OPRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(OPRequestProcessor.java:656)
    at org..struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:341)
    at org..struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org..struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221)
    at com..apps.common.util.OPRequestProcessor.process(OPRequestProcessor.java:248)
    at org..struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org..struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1408)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:553)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3666)
    at com..wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.processSecurityPreInvokeException(CollaboratorHelper.java:145)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1199)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com..ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com..ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com..ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com..ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com..ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com..ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
    at com..ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:694)
    at com..ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com..ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com..io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com..io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com..io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com..io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com..io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com..io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com..ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
2021-01-05 17:07:24,200
ERROR HttpContext on 
Application Error!
[WebContainer : 3](LoggingHelper.java:129)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.apps.common.util.HttpContext.getAdminService(HttpContext.java:318)
    at com.apps.common.util.HttpContext.checkForProfileChange(HttpContext.java:908)
    at com.apps.common.util.HttpContext.getMenuData(HttpContext.java:925)
    at com.apps.sosa.util.MenuUtil.createMenuData(MenuUtil.java:181)
    at com.apps.sosa.util.MenuUtil.createTopLevelMenuData(MenuUtil.java:208)
    at com.apps.sosa.SoxPageLoaderAction.getTopLevelMenuData(SoxPageLoaderAction.java:208)
    at com.apps.common.PageLoaderAction.doLoad(PageLoaderAction.java:169)
    at com.apps.common.AbstractPageLoaderAction.doLoad(AbstractPageLoaderAction.java:99)
    at com.apps.common.AbstractLoaderAction.execute(AbstractLoaderAction.java:176)
    at com.apps.common.util.OPRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(OPRequestProcessor.java:656)
    at org.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:341)
    at org.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221)
    at com.apps.common.util.OPRequestProcessor.process(OPRequestProcessor.java:248)
    at org.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1408)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:553)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3666)
    at com.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.processSecurityPreInvokeException(CollaboratorHelper.java:145)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1199)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
    at com.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:694)
    at com.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
-- nested by --
2021-01-05 17:07:24
CODE       : 00002
LEVEL      : 4
NAME       : com.apps.common.util.ApplicationException
ERROR #    : UTUG12S6W7J0
TOKEN ID   : 2574334
USER       : 100940297
IP         : 10.174.25.221
HOST       : xpe1.net
```

For testing purposes, I have created a txt file that I am updating every 5 minutes, either with the specific error message or with irrelevant words, and not actually with the above log.

My while loop code:

```
$File = 'D:\...\...\logs\Nikos_text2.txt'
$content = Get-Content $File
While($true){
$date = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$Writetime = Get-Item $File | select lastwritetime | get-date
If ($Writetime -le $date -and $content -like  '*Trigger action error*'){
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("server name")
    $objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $objMailMessage.From = "support@domain.com"
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.Subject = "Error message: 'Trigger action error'"
    $objMailMessage.Body = "In log in server (SI) I traced the following error message: Trigger action error. Pls check it asap"
    $smtp.send($objMailMessage)

}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
}
```

After a lot of research I made some modifications to my code, which unfortunately still doesn't work. I think that the key on what I need is to either capture the line or add a timestamp where I could say to start checking the log after the specific timestamp:

```
 $time = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' -f (Get-Date '2021-02-02 12:40:48').AddMinutes(-5)
$File = 'D:\...\...\logs\...log'
$search = 'Application Error*'
$query = (Get-Content $File) | Where-Object {$_-match $search} | Select-Object -Last 1 
if ($query -match "Application Error*" -and ($_ -split ',')[0] -gt $time) {
  $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("server")
    $objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $objMailMessage.From = "support@domain.com"
    #$objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.Subject = "Error message: 'Application error'"
    $objMailMessage.Body = "In log in server I traced the following error message: Application error"
    $smtp.send($objMailMessage)
    }
```

But still, I am not able to receive an Email after adding this piece of code:
...`-and ($_ -split ',')[0] -gt $time) Before, I was able to receive the Email notification but when I ran the script after 5 minutes, I was still capturing the previous entry...`

Comment: Where are you planning on saving the data, and how are you checking if the last error is a new one? What you have just looks to see if there's any error in the file (in theory, since the code you posted doesn't really work, but the intent is there), and makes sure the file was updated in the last 5 minutes. Are you saving to the registry? A log file? Alternate Data Stream?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, I don't want to save any data, I just need to know (by Email) whether a new entry of the specific error message exists in the log.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the log file? If you don't keep a persistent session running that sends your emails you need some way to know externally from the script if the data is updated since the last run. So either you save something showing when the last error happened, or you know from inside the log, or something.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thank you for your comment. I have attached a sample of the log. I took your advise and actually created a while loop that runs every 5 minutes. (I have also attached the code ) Unfortunately, now I get an Email even though I haven't updated my custom log. (That means that it is keep on capturing the same error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with your revamp with the `While` loop... you were *so* close! When PowerShell evaluates a comparison it uses the type of the left hand object to perform the comparison. In your case you have:

```
($_ -split ',')[0] -gt $time
```

Now `($_ -split ',')[0]` is just text, it's a `[string]`. It quite likely contains a valid date for the string, but it is still just a string. So PowerShell converts (or at least tries to) `$time` to a string, and then does the comparison. If you just reverse it PowerShell will see that `$time` is a `[datetime]` object, and will try to convert `($_ -split ',')[0]` to be a time object as well, and perform the comparison on two times which is really what you want. What you have may very well work by changing that to:

```
$time -lt ($_ -split ',')[0]
```

**But wait, there's more!**

Your log has timestamps in it, that makes this much better! First get your log as one multi-line string, then split on lines that begin with your timestamp pattern, and parse for times that happened in the last 5 minutes!

```
$RawLog = Get-Content 'D:\...\...\logs\...log' -Raw
If($RawLog -split '(?sm)[\r\n](?=\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)'|Where{[datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-5) -lt $_.Substring(0,18) -and $_ -match 'Application Error!'}){
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("server")
    $objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $objMailMessage.From = "support@domain.com"
    #$objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("support@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.Subject = "Error message: 'Application error'"
    $objMailMessage.Body = "In log in server I traced the following error message: Application error"
    $smtp.send($objMailMessage)
    }
```

To break that down a little, we first get the whole log as one long string (with line breaks intact and all that). After that we split the log by looking for either a Carriage Return or New Line character (as represented by `[\r\n]`), with a RegEx Look Ahead looking for 4 numbers, a hyphen, 2 numbers, a hyphen, 2 numbers, a space, 2 numbers, colon, 2 numbers, colon, 2 numbers. The way this work is that it removes that new line character, and splits the big string into two parts, then moves on through the second part and keeps doing that splitting it into individual records. For the sample log you provided we end up with 6 records, the last of which is:

```
2021-01-05 17:07:24
CODE       : 00002
LEVEL      : 4
NAME       : com.apps.common.util.ApplicationException
ERROR #    : UTUG12S6W7J0
TOKEN ID   : 2574334
USER       : 100940297
IP         : 10.174.25.221
HOST       : xpe1.net
```

Then we send each of those records through a `Where` statement where it checks if the record as a whole matches your search string, and then compares `[datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-5)`, which is a `[datetime]` object to `$_.Substring(0,18)`, which is the first 18 characters of the current record, or in this case `2021-01-05 17:07:24`. Since the left hand item is a `[datetime]` it will try to convert `2021-01-05 17:07:24` to a `[datetime]`, which it can totally do, and checks to see if that happened in the last 5 minutes. If any of the records both match the search text, and happened in the last 5 minutes they'll make it past the `Where` statement, which makes the `If()` evaluate to `$true` and it will execute the code in the scriptblock.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. This stops others from spending time trying to come up with their own answers, and also helps others in the future who may have the same issue as you find a solution quickly. Thanks!